# save cookie in JavaScript and fetch cookies in php

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I have Following pseudo Code

```
<script>
  var a=fetching data which taking  much time; 
  document.cookie = "testing="+a;
</script>

<?php
$testing=$_COOKIE["testing"];
echo($testing);
?>
```

I m trying to get a single string value from Third party Api which taking almost 5 seconds using my internet . When I set timeout it work fine and save value in cookie. But when I run above code it. I does not saved the value and go to Php Scripting. I want that first Cookies should be set using Script than we should go to PHP

Comment: its work fine when I use set timeout function 
this is because of synchronous behavior of JavaScript.
before fetch and save data in cookie from api. Php code runs

Comment: Go and have a good, thorough read of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you should be able to access cookies with the superglobal `$_COOKIE`.

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php

What is important to know, you have to set the cookie with `document.cookie` so PHP can access this. `window.cookie` cannot be read by PHP.

But **the cookie is only available on the next page reload** and not on the first page state since it is initially set there. So maybe ajax is a possibility here to pass it to PHP, if you don't want to reload the page. It depends what you want to do.

Comment: I m access cookies with  the superglobal $_COOKIE. and have set the cookie with document.cookie in code.this was just pseudo code to make better understanding .
but the problem is because of synchronous behavior of JavaScript. before fetch and save data in cookie from api. Php code runs.
When I use Settimeout function in javascript.I get Value of cookie in Php